# custom HttpParameterBinding not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I added a custom parameter binding to my ASP.net MVC app (version 5.2.0), by adding the following to Global.asax.cs

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, desc => new NewtonsoftParameterBinding(desc));
```

The definition of `NewtonsoftParameterBinding` is

```
public class NewtonsoftParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

    public NewtonsoftParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor) : base(descriptor) {}

    public override bool WillReadBody
    {
        get { return true; }
    }


    public override async Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var theString = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        actionContext.ActionArguments[Descriptor.ParameterName] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(theString, Descriptor.ParameterType, _serializerSettings);
    }
}
```

So I was hoping this would allow me to use things like `JsonProperty` on my MVC model fields, but it's never called. Does anyone know how I can correctly register a custom `ParameterBindingRules`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the HttpParameterBinding to ParameterBindingRules globally will attempt to bind all the parameters in all the actions in this way. Are all your params of type object?

I hope I'm not missing something major here but if you have an action parameter of type `int` how can you assign it to whatever Deserialize returns (which is an `object`)?

Consider deriving from `ParameterBindingAttribute`. This way you can apply your binding logic to where it make sense.

Start by overriding the GetBinding method:

```
public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor httpParamDescriptor)
```

Then use the HttpParameterDescriptor to check if its type makes sense (in your case it should be of 'object').

```
if(httpParamDescriptor.ParameterType == typeof(object))
{
    return new NewtonSoftParameterBinding(); 
}
else
{
    //indicate that this binding doesn't work for non-object types as follows
    return httpParamDescriptor.BindAsError("works with params of object type only");
}
```